# Configuring AWS Session with boto3 in production mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I am running something that uses AWS services on a production server. The most often provided solutions for providing credentials to session are one of:

```py
from boto3 import Session

session = Session(profile_name='my_aws_profile')
```

OR

```py
from boto import Session

session = Session(
    aws_access_key_id="AWS_ACCESS_KEY",
    aws_secret_access_key="AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
)
```

What are my options so that I can

- share the code without sharing my credentials, and
- specify the path of my aws credentials file instead of assuming that it has to be `~/.aws/credentials`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation lists all the ways Boto can find AWS credentials: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#configuring-credentials

In particular, the best practice would be to put credentials in environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`. Boto will pick those up automatically.

Answer (score 1):

save your credentials as environment variables
if you want another location for your credentials, save it in the config file and change set the AWS_CONFIG_FILE location to your desired path. If you have credentials stored in credentials file and config file, the one in the credentials file takes precedence.